# Edit Java security URL list programmatically

Tags: java, security, applet, japplet

My question is about Java Security. I've a Servlet that loads an applet in browsers that try to connect to it.

Now, I know that I have to add the URL containing my applet resource in order to not having security problem. Just I don't know prior IP address of the server, so I would ask for a way to edit Java Security list programmatically.

Comment: *"I know that I have to add the URL containing my applet resource in order to not having security problem."*  Not sure what you mean by that, but is seems wrong.  Security problems are solved by digitally signing the applet code.

Comment: I sign my jar but I get security problem the same. To be more clear, even if I sign my jar, when I try to run my applet in browser, my application is blocked because it must satisfy security requiriment high or very high and it must be in the site exception list to be run.

Comment: *"I sign my jar.."*  Is that using a code signing certificate issued by a certification authority?